# new array from csv data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have the following csv data:

```
id,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
Lo,32,45,37,53,22
```

I want to create new array which looks this way:

```
id2,value
v1,32
v2,45
v3,37
v4,53
v5,22
```

To do it I use the following code:

```
d3.csv("dataSBar1.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

var values = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "id";});  

data.forEach(function(d) {
 for (var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {
    d.value = +d[values[i]];
  return d;}});     

  /*---------- create new array ----------*/

var array = $.map(data, function (d) {
for( var i=0; i<=values.length; i++){
    return {
        id2: values[i],
        value: d[values[i]]
    }
  }
});
```

It returns me only

```
0: Object
   id2: "v1"
   value: "32"
```

and nothing more.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're breaking out of the final for loop on the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need so many for loops simply do as below:

```
d3.csv("my.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  //get all values without id    
  var values = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "id";
  });
  //iterate through the values and get the value using map.
  var id2 = values.map(function(id, index) {
    return {
      "id2": id,
      "value": +data[0][id]
    };

  });
  console.log(id2)
});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmcchza00K8o72HWFLh3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, if you return inside a loop, the loop stops, so you want to create an inner variable to store the result from the loop over values or use another map.

Something like this might work as well, if both arrays always have the same length:

```
var id2 = id.map(function( id, index ) {
    return {
        "id2" : id,
        "value" : lo[index]
    };
});
```